# Regex expression for exact match on multiple

Tags: jquery, regex, datatable, datatables

I'm trying to figure out how to write the correct regex so when jquery DataTables searches one column it finds exact matches.  I have values of C-, C+, C and if someone clicks "C" I need it to only grab exact matches of C and not the other 2.

If they choose C- and C it should grab all entries with either of those 2, but C+ shouldn't be included.

I tried regex of: "C-|C+" but it grabs all C as well.

Here's the code I have creating that regex:

```
$("input[name='tourneyLevel']").on("change", function(e) {
    var levelSelected = [];
    $("input[name='tourneyLevel']:checked").each(function(index, city) {
        levelSelected.push([$(this).val()]);
    });

    var regex = levelSelected.join("|");
    console.log(regex);

    $('.dataTable').DataTable().column(4).search(regex, true, false).draw();
});
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

"+" and "-" tend to have special meaning in RegEx. When constructing your RegEx try to escape them and put the phrases in a group, as you want to match the complete group.

So your user is searching for "C+"?

`(C\+)`

Your user is searching for "C" or "C-"?

`(C\-)|(C)`

Your user is searching for "C-" or "C+"?

`(C\-)|(C\+)`

Your user is searching for any of the three possibilities?

`(C\-)|(C)|(C\+)`

The plus sign normally means "one or more of the previous group". A minus is often used in ranges or to exclude stuff. Be careful when searching for these special characters. And when searching for multiple characters in a specific order you should try to group them with parentheses.

Furthermore the backslash is used to escape characters in a string. When constructing a RegEx by concatenating strings you have to escape the backslash with a second backslash so that the resulting RegEx contains a single backslash. This may sound complicated, but it boils down to:

Use two backslashes to escape a character in your RegEx when you are constructing the RegEx by concatenating strings.

To make sure that only this specific sequence is matched you can use two more important special characters:

- `^` for the start
- `$` for the end

For example you can use the RegEx `(^C$)` to only match exactly a single "C". The sequence starts, contains exactly the character "C" and ends when using this RegEx.

Comment: ok so I did some if else statements for checkboxes to generate that regex, but it still seems to pull other values.  When i searched for C- and C+ it grabs all C... the regex it spit out was:  (C-)|(C+)

Comment: (C) still pulls all 3 values:  C, C-, and C+..... Not sure if it's problem with dataTables or my regex still

Comment: @Chief Remember that the plus and minus have to be escaped. So if the regex is (C+) it won't work the intended way. It has to be (C\+). Try to escape the backslash in your strings, so that you write something like (C\\+) which might result in a regex like (C\+).

Comment: ok that worked for the C+ and C-... I just had to add an extra slash to get the right regex value.  Those 2 are now working properly, however the regex (c) is still pulling all 3.  getting close!  any ideas on that one?

Comment: @Chief Try (^C$). This should make sure that the sequence starts, contains only the "C" and then ends. The two characters are the special characters for start and end. That might help.

Comment: you are a genius!  that worked.  Thanks so much for all the help :)

Comment: @Chief Not a genius, just had my fair share of problems with RegEx in different languages in the past :D Glad I could help you. Happy Coding ;)

Comment: how to escape parenthesis like if user want to search (grocery)